# what is the advantages of using 2-μm operating wavelength light in sdm/mdm technology?

Tags: optics, research-level, fiber-optics, waveguide

Most of the work have been done in the communication band but recently there has been emerging interest in extending the operating wavelength of communication system to the short-wave infrared (2 μm). Now what is the advantage/disadvantage/feature of this 2 μm wavelength for on chip mux/demux or for other feature?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.